# How to float divs top to bottom with jQuery like the new layout for myspace.com?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-float, horizontal-scrolling

so thats gonna be a big challenge. Its about HOW TO display thumbnails/gallery just like they've done on https://myspace.com/ using the horizontal layout. It looks like they are floating from top to bottom and left to right, i know theres no `float:top` but i was wondering if theres a way to achieve that layout with jQuery/Javascript? View the image link below to have a better understanding of what I'm trying to achieve.

Mockup
[image: http://public.coco.com.au/empty-projects/columns/assets/img/mockup.png]

So what I've tried so far is to `.slice()` every two li(s) inside a div .wrap and flot that div left. it kind of did the job but as soon as you have a bigger image (see example suqare n6) it brakes.

I also tried to rotate the entire container using css3 `-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg)` and also it didnt work as the thumbnails have to be using percentages in order to fluid scale when browser resizing.

I also used a jQuery plugin called masonry and it didn't work out well

Can you guys please help? I'd really like to make this layout work.

Comment: Nice idea, but can you please show your codes ?

Comment: Yeah sure man http://jsfiddle.net/WTBxt/ . you can also view this page where i do my testings http://public.coco.com.au/empty-projects/starter-template-horizontal/ . I think its a pretty interesting concept myspace.com came up with :)

Comment: People still use myspace?!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I been trying to figure out this layout also and the closest I got was using PHP/JAVASCRIPT to build it.

The idea is to 
1) build and array of all the positions possible using one size.
2) Then go through that array and flag the possible positions in the array as open.
3) Then run through the new list of positions and display the open spots.

This is the code that I got so far. This produces 300px X 300px boxes, and inserts 600 x 600 px box where ever you specify int he array.

I hope this helps and if you figure out a way to improve this please post it.

FYI: I am really new to posting here and seem to have trouble posting the code properly.

ARRAY:

```
            $mod[ 0 ] = array( 600 );
            $mod[ 1 ] = array( 300 );
            $mod[ 2 ] = array( 300 );
            $mod[ 3 ] = array( 300 );
            $mod[ 4 ] = array( 300 );
            $mod[ 5 ] = array( 300 );
```

PHP:

```
    define( 'XPOS', 0 );
    define( 'YPOS', 1 );
    define( 'WIDTH', 2 );

    $pos = array();
            $x = 0;
            $y = 0;
            $width = 300;
            for( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($mod); ++$i )
            {
                $width = $mod[$i][0];
                $shifted = $mod[$i][1];

                $pos[ $i ] = array( $x, $y, $width, $shifted );

                $y += 300;
                if( $y >= (300 * 3) )
                {
                    $x += 300;
                    $y = 0;
                }
            }   

            for( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($pos); ++$i )
            {
                if( $pos[$i][WIDTH] > 300 )
                {
                    $pos[$i +1][3] = 1;
                    $pos[$i +3][3] = 1;
                    $pos[$i +4][3] = 1;
                }
            }


            for( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($pos); ++$i )
            {
                if( $pos[$i][3] == 0 )
                {
                    echo 'X:' . $pos[$i][XPOS] . ' - Y:' . $pos[$i][YPOS] . ' - W:' . $pos[$i][WIDTH] . ' - S:' . $pos[$i][3] . '<br/>';
                    echo '<li class="collage-img" style="height:' . $pos[$i][WIDTH] . 'px;width:' . $pos[$i][WIDTH] . 'px;" data-xpos="'. $pos[$i][XPOS] .'" data-ypos="'. $pos[$i][YPOS] .'">' . $i . '</li>';
                }
            }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    var counter = 0;
    $('.collage-list li').each(function(){

        var x = $(this).data( 'xpos' );
        var y = $(this).data( 'ypos' );

        $(this).css( 'position', 'absolute' );
        $(this).css( 'top', '0' );
        $(this).css( 'left', '0' );
        $(this).css( 'transform', 'translate('+ x +'px, '+ y +'px)' );
        $(this).css( '-webkit-transform', 'translate('+ x +'px, '+ y +'px)' );
        $(this).text( counter + ' - (X:' + x + ' Y:' + y + ')' );       

        counter++;
    });
```